# Get Firestore document with OR query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to store a Friend List for my iOS app, which is using Swift.

each document in my `friends` collection has a `sender`, `target`, and `accepted` field

when the user opens their friend list I need the app to retrieve every document where their user ID is in either the `target` or `sender` fields, and only where `accepted == true`

I know I can chain `.where()` functions to create AND queries.

but as far as I can see it's not possible to do OR queries with Firestore.

Is there a way to do this in one query?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a snapshot of the database structure

[image]

Each document is created when a friend request is sent and is then used to build the friend list for both users when required (rather than storing 2 arrays of user IDs which have to be updated separately whenever a change is made)

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your database structure and then explain which fields are you looking for?

Comment: I made some small changes to my question to make it a little clearer, but everything you asked for is already available in the question @Dharmaraj

Comment: The document structure is still unclear to me. Is `accepted` field an array or a map? Are you storing an array of userIDs who are friends of a user? A sample screenshot would really help

Comment: While there are no direct "or" style queries as shown by @frankvanpuffelen, you can often leverage an array to provide a similar functionality. I tossed out an answer with code that solves this with a single query (per Franks answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the app to retrieve every document where their user ID is in either the target or sender fields

This is not possible, as Firestore does not allow OR conditions between fields.

The closest you can get is adding an array field to the document where you keep the UIDs of all participants, and then [checking whether the UID you're looking for is in that array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) with an `in` operation:

```
friendsRef
  .whereField("participants", arrayContains: "uidOfUser")
```

Comment: shoot, I was hoping to avoid extensive lists of strings that have to be updated whenever a friend connection changes :/ .... it boggles the mind why google don't think OR queries are important enough to include in their API 0.o 

Thanks :)

Comment: so with this in mind, Would it be more efficient to have a `friends` array field in each user document, or keep what I started with (see the new screenshot above) and just run 2 queries (one for each field).... The former option seems (to me) like it has more potential for errors

Comment: "it boggles the mind why google don't think OR queries are important" Firestore only allows queries for which is can meet its performance guarantee that query performance does not in any way depend on the number of documents that are being queries, and only on the amount of data that is actually returned. It cannot meet this guarantee for an OR across multiple fields.

Answer (score 1):

See Franks correct answer, going outside the box a bit with arrays presents a solution. I wanted to show the structure we use to handle these cases (based on Franks answer)

Firebase can check for values in an array, so simply changing the structure allows an "or" style query. Here's some sample data

```
friends
   doc_0
      accepted: true
      requests //an array
         0: uid_0
         1: uid_2
   doc_1
      accepted: true
      requests
         0: uid_6
         1: uid_0
   doc_2
      accepted: true
      requests
         0: uid_1
         1: uid_6
```

Keep in mind that with this structure, array element 0 is the "sender" and array element 1 is the "target"

In this case suppose user 0 (uid_0) wants all of the docs where their users uid (uid_0) is either in the "sender" or "target" position, which would be doc_0 or doc_1. Here's the code

```
func getRequests() {
    let friendsCollection = self.db.collection("friends") //self.db points to my firebase
    let query = friendsCollection.whereField("accepted", isEqualTo: true)
                                 .whereField("requests", arrayContains: "uid_0")
    query.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs {
            let docId = doc.documentID
            print(docId)
        }
    })
}
```

And the result

```
doc_0
doc_1
```